# Group By and Fill With tidyr and dyplr Does Not Execute

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
Store <- c('A','A','A', 'B','C','C')
Main_or_branch <- c('main', 'Branch','Branch','main','main', 'Branch')
flavor <- c('chocolate', 'N/A','N/A', 'vanilla', 'strawberry','N/A')

df <- data.frame(Store, Main_or_branch, flavor)
```

and it looks like this:

```
 Store Main_or_branch flavor    
 <fct> <fct>          <fct>     
1 A     main           chocolate 
2 A     Branch         N/A       
3 A     Branch         N/A       
4 B     main           vanilla   
5 C     main           strawberry
6 C     Branch         N/A
```

I'm trying to use group by and fill :

```
df %>% group_by(Store) %>% fill(flavor)
```

but my output still looks like this

```
  Store Main_or_branch flavor    
  <fct> <fct>          <fct>     
1 A     main           chocolate 
2 A     Branch         N/A       
3 A     Branch         N/A       
4 B     main           vanilla   
5 C     main           strawberry
6 C     Branch         N/A
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be? running version tidyr 1.1.4
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Store) %>%
   mutate(flavor = na.locf(na_if(flavor, "N/A"))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Store Main_or_branch flavor    
  <chr> <chr>          <chr>     
1 A     main           chocolate 
2 A     Branch         chocolate 
3 A     Branch         chocolate 
4 B     main           vanilla   
5 C     main           strawberry
6 C     Branch         strawberry
```

Answer (score 0):

"N/A" is not the same as `NA`. Here you go:

```
df[df == "N/A"] <- NA  # Substitute all instances of "N/A" with NA

df %>% group_by(Store) %>% fill(flavor)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Store [3]
  Store Main_or_branch flavor    
  <chr> <chr>          <chr>     
1 A     main           chocolate 
2 A     Branch         chocolate 
3 A     Branch         chocolate 
4 B     main           vanilla   
5 C     main           strawberry
6 C     Branch         strawberry
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to convert the string NAs to actual `NA`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    flavor = na_if(flavor, 'N/A')
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Store) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(flavor)
```